# data from my db returns partial content from my Restful API (206 partial content)...

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, restangular

im having a little problem with my M.E.A.N(mongo, express, angular, node) application, when i do a GET request from my node server, it displays on 10 items instead of all 21 that are in the mongo db. i did some search on google and i read stuff saying it had to do with my CORS set up on my servers side, but i still cant seem to figure it out... here's my code:

index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var methodOverride = require('method-override');
var _ = require('lodash');
var cors = require('cors');


// Create the application.
var app = express();


//enable the use of cors
app.use(cors());




// Add Middleware necessary for REST API's
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(methodOverride('X-HTTP-Method-Override'));



// CORS Support
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

next();
});


app.models = require('./models/index');

// Load the routes.
var routes = require('./routes');
_.each(routes, function(controller, route) {
    app.use(route, controller(app, route));
});



// Connect to MongoDB
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/isdbmeanapp');
mongoose.connection.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {

// Load the models.
app.models = require('./models/index');

app.listen(3000);                           
console.log('Server running on localhost port 3000...');
});
```

i currently have 21 users(dummy data) in my database(mongodb) but when i run the above restangular query, it displays only 10 users. i also tried making requests with postman and thesame thing happens (with a 206 server status code).

im using restangular to make my requests:

```
Restangular.all('user').getList().then(function(user){
$scope.users = user;
});
```

please i need help in solving this problem... thanks in advance...

Comment: If it was a CORS problem, you wouldn’t get anything at all—the fact that you’re getting 10 out of 21 says it’s not CORS. Probably you need to tell Mongoose to fetch a certain number of documents, which defaults to ten if you don’t specify. This default is reasonable: most NoSQL dbs paginate responses, whereas a SQL RDBMS usually won’t by default. Since you don’t post your `routes.js`, we can’t tell what your Mongoose query looks like but most likely “max number of documents returned” is a parameter there.

Comment: im using restangular for my queries, as shown here : Restangular.all('user').getList().then(function(user){
$scope.users = user;
});